# how to use arrays in sql script to accept n number and display

Tags: sql

how to write a script to accept 5 names and print that in sqlplus oracle. below is my code.

```
DECLARE
TYPE MyArray IS TABLE OF varchar2(100);
names myArray := MyArray(n);
Prompt Enter how many names you want:
Accept n Prompt "Number of Names:"
Prompt Enter names one by one:

BEGIN
FOR i in names.FIRST ..n LOOP
What to write here
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I am not getting how to do this please help me i am new to sql scripting.

Comment: Are you trying to drop all contents of a table? That is not clear from your question, but it is in your code.

Comment: hELLO SIR, TQS FOR REPLY, BEFORE THAT I NEED TO DISPLAY THE NAMES WHICH I HAVE ENTERED.

Comment: Actually i am looking for different. i need to grant a quotas on tablespace oracle. i ll post my code below.

Comment: DECLARE
  TYPE MyArray IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
  quotas myArray := MyArray('COL_LEV_SEC', 'newtg');
BEGIN
  FOR i IN quotas.FIRST ..quotas.LAST LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter user &&username quota unlimited on ' || quotas(i);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

Comment: In the above code, i have declared my array elements but i want to tke it dynamically. and print the same. first it has to ask number of quotas to grant, then it reads the values, then asks enter the names one by one and print the entered values and assign array elements to alter user command

Comment: can anybody please help me.